# How to send form values of array/list without correct indexing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's assume that we have model and View like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<string> data { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<form asp-action="View">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <input name="data[0]" value="dsa" />
    <input name="data[1]" value="asd" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult View(Test input)
{
    return View();
}
```

I'm sending this form to the controller's method and he sees those elements of data properly.

But if I change indexing to:

```
<input name="data[0]" value="dsa" />
<input name="data[2]" value="asd" />
```

then it is not going to work. I know that it makes sense in this way, but is there an option to disable index checking and just insert all those values into list/array with correct indexing?

So, in 2nd case `data[0]` would be `data[0]`, but `data[1]` would be `data[2]`.

Just for every "gap" in indexing, move Next objs to fil lthat gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just:

```
<input name="data[]" value="dsa" />
<input name="data[]" value="asd" />
```

If you specify the index at all, though, it must be in order.

Comment: It works, but when data[] is complexObj[] then e.g ``data[].Name`` does not work, but ``data[0].Name`` does - how to fix that?

Comment: You can't. You need to use correct indexes. If you're attempting to dynamically add items, it's best to use a templating/data-binding client-side library like Vue, Knockout, Angular, etc. That way it will automatically index your field names based on the position in the backing JS array.

Comment: I think there's a hack for that. I will consume that List<string> into my ``InputModel`` and then map it to List<ComplexObject>in C#.